# US Tourist Visa, different name on passport and visa

Tags: visas, usa

My mom's passport has Last name/ Surname blank, while the US tourist visa has the First as FNU. Will this be a problem for entering US.

Answer (score 5):

No.  [From the US embassy in the UK](https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/visa-errors/name-appears-as-fnu/):

> This is not an error.  The visa is issued in the name that appears in the passport.  FNU means First Name Unknown.
>
> If the surname is not included in the passport as in the following example: Given Name: Happy Traveler; Surname: Blank.
>
> The visa will be issued as follows: Given Name: FNU; Surname: Happy Traveler
>
> If the passport contains only the surname of the holder and not a given name as in the following example: Given Name: blank; Surname: Happy Traveler
>
> The visa will be issued as follows: Given Name: FNU; Surname: Happy Traveler

Comment: Appreciate your response. Do you know with what name it is preferable to book her flight tickets in that case?

Comment: @visaquestion Use the name shown in the passport.